# writing "latex command" in the Matlab figure comment

Tags: matlab, latex, figure

I have a figure in Matlab, inside the figure i would like to write comments on the figure.
the comment include latex formula; for example, I want to write this comment on my figure  $$ \vec{R} = 2 $$

here is an example that I found when I searched;

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
figure
ms = 8;
fontSize = 18;
xx = 0:.1:1;
plot(xx,sin(xx))
xlabel('P_{fa}', 'fontsize', fontSize);
ylabel('P_{m}', 'fontsize', fontSize);
```

I want it looks like as in the attached figure below:
[image]

Note: I searched in last questions that already answered, I found that I can write latex commands in the legend, title, axis ... but not when writing comments inside the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy: just add a [`text`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) object with its `'interpreter'` property set to `'latex'`:

```
text(.3, .5, '$\vec R=2$', 'interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', fontSize)
```

The first two arguments of `text` are coordinates; change them as needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very useful and nice.
I have another question which is also related to the question above:
How I can write multi line comment? for example if I want to write
$$ R=2; \\
K=3; \\
M=5 $$

not in the same horizontal line, I want them to be vertically listed.
I think it can be done by writing several line of the code that you suggested. but I wonder if I can do that using one line command

Comment: It works (at least in Matlab R2014b) if you use a cell array of strings: `text(.3, .5, {'$\vec R=2$', '$K=3$', '$M=5$'}, 'interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', fontSize)`