# Excel MathType Equation from matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

Is it possible to insert a **mathType** equation from **matlab** into the **excel** spreadsheet?

I am going to create an excel file through matlab and create a pdf report. My report includes some formula and I want to create them with excel MathType equation. Is there any access to MathType equation from activeX in matlab?

Comment: Does anybody know the Excel MathType  equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require creating a MathType equation, then adding it as an object to the Excel file through ActiveX. I haven't found any way to call MathType from MATLAB, let alone move the resulting object to the file.

One alternative is to [plot your formula in a MATLAB figure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28928295/52738), then [capture and insert the figure as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45821380/52738) into your Excel file through ActiveX. Here's an example for plotting the formula:

```
hFigure = figure('Position', [100 100 300 200], 'Color', 'w');   % Create white figure
hAxes = axes(hFigure, 'Position', [0 0 1 1], 'Visible', 'off');  % Create invisible axes
text(hAxes, 0.5, 0.5, '$$y = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i*x_i$$', ...        % Create equation text
     'Interpreter', 'latex', ...
     'FontSize', 30, ...
     'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
```

And the resulting figure:

[image]

Now you can print this figure to the clipboard and insert it into an Excel worksheet with ActiveX:

```
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');  % Create server object
excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(1);   % Add a workbook
excelSheet = excel.ActiveSheet;           % Get the active sheet
dpi = get(groot, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch');  % Get screen dpi
print(hFigure, sprintf('-r%d', dpi), ...  % Print the figure at the screen resolution
      '-clipboard', '-dbitmap');          %   to the clipboard as a bitmap
excelSheet.Range('B2').PasteSpecial();    % Paste from clipboard (top left corner
                                          %   of image will be in the cell 'B2')
excelWorkbook.SaveAs('formula.xlsx');     % Save workbook to a file
excelWorkbook.Close();                    % Close workbook
excel.Quit();                             % Quit server
excel.delete();                           % Delete server object
```

And here's how it looks in the Excel file:

[image]